# Injection for method argument

Tags: twig, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to "Language Inject" HTML for argument in the custom Twig method?

I have a custom method and the second argument is a text with HTML.
I checked how to make a new injection rule but only what I found is for a Twig block-like style type: `+ twigCustomStatement("javascript")` for `{% javascript %}{% endjavascript  %}`.

I tried to use `twigCustomStatement` with a method but without any luck...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What is `twigCustomStatement`? What is the expected output?

Comment: if you Google it will see, that it is a parameter for PhpStorm to determine some "place patterns" for language injection, check out this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vris.png). I search a lot to find place patterns for the method, but nothing, even could not find any kind of documentation about those patterns.

Comment: Please clarify with an example code/screenshot where you want such injection. The 2 options currently supported by the Twig plugin are for things like `{% javascript %}...{% endjavascript %}` and `{% block javascript %}...{endblock %}`. If that's the case then yes, you can make a similar rule for a different block name. If it's something different (e.g. a specific parameter) then no (at very least I'm not aware on them on the top of my head/with what I can think of right now).

Comment: Here is the example: `aform('http://test.1/1','<a href="/2">here</a>')`, the second argument is a HTML, since i use it around 90% of the times when im writing a twig template, will be great to "HTML language inject" it.
I know there is a workaround by defining a `{% set some_var%}` and passing it to the function but will consume extra new lines.

Comment: @fire1 AFAIK there are no methods to make such injections. Only the custom tag or block name. I do not see any noticeable improvements here since the initial feature introduction. https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/12/twig-handling-improvements/ (the [actual WI-11277 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11277)). I may only suggest to file a Feature Request ticket at the [PhpStorm's Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI). Unless such injection can also be provided by Symfony plugin (that adds some extra features for Twig on top of bundled one)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @LazyOne!
For sure I will open a ticket

Comment: For reference purposes: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67544/HTML-Language-injection-for-Twig-method-is-not-possible

Comment: ^_^ you are fast. Thanks for doing my job here... LOL